# Get orders and customers by product_id

Tags: magento-1.8

I am trying to get all the orders for the specific product by that product_id, and customers that have bought that product. The query at the moment is not working as it should - this is getting all orders. If I put **$productId** to be non-existing product there is no result, but if I put real product I am getting all the orders.
Code:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$productId = 297;


$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders
     ->getSelect()
     ->joinInner(array('order_item' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item'), 'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id' ))
     ->where('product_id=?', $productId)
     ->group('main_table.entity_id')
     ->order('main_table.entity_id DESC');

$header = 'date,company,name,city,address,postcode,itemname,quantity,price,sku';
$fields = '';
foreach($orders as $order):

     //$order->getData();
     $order->getIncrementId();
     $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
     $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
     $billingStreet = $billingAddress->getStreet();
     $fields .=
          date('Y-m-d',strtotime($order->getCreatedAt())).','.
          $billingAddress->getCompany().','.
          $billingAddress->getName().','.
          $billingAddress->getCity().','.
          $billingStreet[0].','.
          $billingAddress->getPostcode().','.
          $order->getShippingDescription() .',';

          foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $itemId => $item):
               $itemname =  $item->getName();
               $itemname =  str_replace('&', " ", $itemname);
               $fields .=
                    $itemname. ','.
                    $item->getQtyOrdered().','.
                    $item->getPrice().','.
                    $item->getSku().',';

          endforeach;
     $fields = rtrim($fields, ',');
     $fields .= "\n";    

endforeach;
print "$header\n$fields";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi try this  use  leftjoint

```
 $orders
     ->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
    array('order_item' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item')),
    'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id',
    array('product_id'=>'product_id'))
    ->where('product_id=?', $productId)
    ->group('main_table.entity_id')
     ->order('main_table.entity_id DESC')
     ;
```